# Send php array to a socket

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

How to send a php array to a socket server?
I have a webservice and i want to send a php array to a socket webservices.
How i can do it?

I have tried this:

```
    $host = "170.51.249.101";
    $port = 8080;
    // No Timeout 
    set_time_limit(0);
    // Create a Data to send
    $data = "";
    $data .= "ID_PRESTADOR: ".$service_id."\n";
    $data .= "ID_TERMINAL: ".$atm_id."\n";
    $data .= "NRO_TRANSACCION: 123456\n";
    // Create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    // Connect to the server
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect toserver\n");
    // Write to server socket
    socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    // Read the response from the server
    $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
    echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
    // Close the socket
    socket_close($socket);
    die;
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ???

Comment: You can't! PHP datatypes don't make sense over a network so need to serialize as suggested by @AbraCadaver encode it as json as it's the most easy and reliable encoding.

Comment: You must serialize your array to something that can be handled by websockets. JSON can be a solution.

Comment: The protocol is based on TCP / IP connections and a single exchange type
PETITION / RESPONSE of a message based on ASCII characters, from fields of
fixed length, where the PETITION has the same format as the ANSWER